# R: `which` statement with multiple conditions

Tags: r

I have a matrix which consists of 13 columns (called PCs). I want to make a new matrix including only the rows that have a value between 4 and 8 (called EUR). I tried using this statement:

```
EUR <- PCs[which(PCs$V13 < 9 && PCs$V13 > 3), ]
```

Which unfortunately doesn't work... (I only get one row out, while there are hundreds)

Anyone knows what's wrong with this command?

Comment: Sample data might help others answer your question.

Comment: @Abdel Just like Ryan Thompson has said you can look for the descriptions about &,&& and |, || in the manual.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The `&&` function is not vectorized. You need the `&` function:

```
EUR <- PCs[which(PCs$V13 < 9 & PCs$V13 > 3), ]
```

Comment: Yeah, In the manual it writes that"& and && indicate logical AND and | and || indicate logical OR. The shorter form performs elementwise comparisons in much the same way as arithmetic operators. The longer form evaluates left to right examining only the first element of each vector. Evaluation proceeds only until the result is determined. The longer form is appropriate for programming control-flow and typically preferred in if clauses."